# How to persist file system with Docker?

Tags: javascript, .net, docker, docker-compose

I have a project where I need to store file and persist that file. I first though about saving that file to a database. But after some reading, I notice that almost everyone recommended to use a file system to store file and keep the path to that file in the database.

I don't really want to put some cash into this, I'd really like to make it mostly local. (No AWS or Google file storage system).

I am using a React front end which makes request to a .NET Core 2.2 with E.F. back end.They are both hosted in 2 docker containers and managed by a docker-compose file.

My first though was mounting a volumes to the .NET Core container and using the System.IO function to create, save and list directories and file. It didn't worked for me...

Well, my goal is to save files efficiently and be able to read them from my react front end app. I don't know if I'm heading the right direction.

It's the first time that I'm touching to these kind of things, so if you have any recommendation, tips or whatever, go ahead. I'm here to listen and learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared, bind-mounted volume that both the React and .NET core containers can access, perhaps this would work for your use case.

Take a look at the documentation for docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Under the heading **Volume configuration reference** they give an example of two services using the same file system.